# Windows 7 VPN connection with Home Premium at both ends: Error 720

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm trying to set up a VPN link between my machines, both of which are running Win7 Home Premium (64-bits on one side, 32-bits on the other).

When I try to connect, the client goes through verifying the username and password, but fails when it gets to the point where its registering the computer on the network. The error reported on the client is Error 720.

The event logs on the server shows this:

```
The user [...] connected to port VPN3-2 has been disconnected 
because no network protocols were successfully negotiated.
```

My router firewall is configured for port forwarding on 1723 (PPTP), and VPN passthrough is enabled. Windows firewall seems to have all the necessary rules already enabled so I haven't touched anything there. I don't see how this could be a firewall issue, seeing that the connection is getting established and authorization is successful.

The connection settings are configured to allow only IPv4, and DHCP is enabled.

Am I missing something here? Does this have something to do with the machines being Home Premium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Are both machines on the same subnet?  If they are, then that's your problem.  Both machines can't have the same LAN subnet.  i.e.  192.168.1.x/24
- In RRAS, are you sure that you have IPV4 configured for both sides?  It's basically giving up because it can't assign an IP or IPX address to the VPN client.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that it works when I tell it not to use DHCP to assign an IP, and specify a range manually instead for the incoming connection. Not sure why my router's DHCP can't assign IPs for the VPN connections, but I guess that's another question. :)